# Как сделать у jQuery вызов поля для ввода сообщения и автоматический ответ на него?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть такой код, нужно чтоб после ответа на сообщение появлялся еще вопрос с полем для ответа. Помогите, пожалуйста.

```
<script>

  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("p").append( $("strong") );
  });
  </script>
  <p>Привет! Как тебя зовут?</p>
  </script>

<input type="text" id="input" />
<script type="text/javascript">
function sow(){
    var a;
    a=document.getElementById("input").value

    if (a=='Леонид')  {
         $("p").append("<p>Приятно</p>");

        return false;
    }
    else{   
         $("p").append("<p>Приятно</p>" +a);    
        }
}


</script>
<input class="box" type="button" id="sub" name="submit" value="Отправить" onClick="return sow();">
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<div id="question">Привет как тебя зовут?</div>

<input type='hidden' name="answer" id="answer" value='1'>
<input type="text" name="message" id="message">

<button id="send">Отправить</button>

$('#send').click(function(){
      mes = $("#message").val();
      ans = $("#answer").val();
      switch(ans){
      case '1':
        if(mes=='Леонид') $("#question").html('Очень приятно, а как у тебя дела?');
        else $("#question").html('Приятно, а как у тебя дела?');
        $("#answer").val('2');
      break;
      case '2':
            if(mes=='Хорошо') $("#question").html('У меня тоже хорошо');
            else $("#question").html('Хочешь покушать?');
            $("#answer").val('3');
      break;
      //и т. д. сколько хочешь вопросов
      }

})
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Уверен, автор вопроса был бы благодарен за ваш экспертный комментарий к приведенному выше коду.